# MonoMac Build Error From Default Template

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I am trying to use MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2 to create a MonoMac application. I created a new MonoMac solution and tried running the template created after creating the solution, but this is my build output:

```
Building Solution: MAC1 (Debug|x86)

Building: MAC1 (Debug|x86)
Performing main compilation...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/dmcs /noconfig
"/out:/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/bin/Debug/MAC1.exe"
"/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" 
"/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" 
"/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" 
"/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
"/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" 

"/r:/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 /platform:x86     
"/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/MainWindow.cs"
 "/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/MainWindowController.cs" 
"/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/MainWindow.designer.cs" 
"/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/Main.cs" "/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/AppDelegate.cs" 
"/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/AppDelegate.designer.cs" 

Copying content files
Copying '/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/bin/Debug/MAC1.exe' to
'/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/bin/Debug/MAC1.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MAC1.exe'
Copying '/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/bin/Debug/MAC1.exe.mdb' to 
'/Users/zgillis/Projects/MAC1/bin/Debug/MAC1.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MAC1.exe.mdb'
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

Updating application manifest

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build successful.
Build failed. The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8), and my Xcode version is 3.2.2.

It will not allow me to compile even the default MonoMac template, so I know I must have something configured incorrectly. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your version of Xcode is old - it's likely that MonoDevelop's support for reading values from the older Apple SDKs' plists has regressed. I would suggest you either upgrade Xcode, or [file a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with the MonoDevelop log file (found in ~/Library/Logs/MonoDevelop-3.0) attached.

Comment: My version of Mac will not allow me to upgrade XCode. I am going to be buying the upgrade to Mountain Lion within the next few weeks when they release it. That may help fix the issue. If that does not work, I will definitely submit a bug report.